# 'Столь' versus 'так'

Tags: значения

How does the meaning of 'столь' differ from 'так'? Based on the context of some sentences, I am inclined to view 'столь' as close to the meaning of 'настолько'. Am I correct in this thinking? For example: 'Кроме того, Берлиоза охватил необоснованный, но столь сильный страх, что ему захотелось тотчас же бежать с Патриарших без оглядки.'

Also, is 'столь' useful to know by itself (that is, unique in meaning) or just a secondary synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Столь* (or *настолько*) means quantitative "so" (meaning "so much"), and can be replaced with *так* or *такой* anywhere it cannot be confused with qualitative or classifying "so" (meaning "in the same way").

This means you should avoid using *так* when quantitative meaning is not the only possible one.

Compare two sentences:

> Я не настолько накрашена, чтобы принимать гостей.
>
> Я не так накрашена, чтобы принимать гостей.

The first sentence unequivocally means "I'm not wearing enough makeup to welcome my guests".

The second one is dubious: it might mean both "I'm not wearing the right makeup" or "I'm not wearing enough makeup". Though this sentence is a little bit ungrammatical if parsed according to the first meaning, this first meaning is what most people would perceive from this sentence.

Answering you second question, yes, *столь* and *настолько* are complete synonyms, *столь* being the grand style form.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting to note that '**столь**' in the quote you give cannot be replaced with '**так**', but would require '**такой**' instead.

The difference in meaning between '**столь**' and '**так**' does not really exist.  Both are adverbs in the use where they are synonyms, but keep in mind that '**столь**' (or its full prototype '**настолько**') can be used to modify adverbs as well as adjectives, but '**так**' turns into '**такой**' (такая, такое) with adjectives.

Here are some examples.  Italics designate adjectives

> Я Вас любил **так** искренно, **так** нежно...
>   Не **столь** *страшен* грипп, как его осложнения.
>   Вы **столь** *забывчивы*, сколь незабвенны.
>   Голос у нее ***такой*** *тихий*, ***такой*** *нежный*, ***такой*** *невинный*...
>   Опять выглянуло солнышко, да ***такое*** *весёлое*, яркое!

---

As [Quassnoi](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/134/quassnoi) points out (thank you!), with shortened adjectives the shortened form of '**такой**' ('*такая*', '*такое*') -- '**так**' -- is used:

> Начался штурм города, и **так** силён был натиск армии семерых вождей...

Comment: *так* is used with short forms of adjectives, *такой* with full forms: *такой сильный / так силён*.